# ImportError: No module named time

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to get a Google app up and running on my local machine, however, am facing an issue when running the setup scripts. The script errors out and tells me that there is no module time and seems to be breaking in the google-cloud-sdk....

Things I've tried:

1. Importing time in Python (it works)
2. Trying this to no avail: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96308/python-installation-messed-up

   ```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/Users/kennethryan/Projects/go-edu-store/y/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py", line 83, in <module>
   _run_file(__file__, globals())
     File "/Users/kennethryan/Projects/go-edu-store/y/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/_python_runtime.py", line 79, in _run_file
   execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
     File "/Users/kennethryan/Projects/go-edu-store/y/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime.py", line 175, in <module>
   main()
     File "/Users/kennethryan/Projects/go-edu-store/y/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/runtime.py", line 155, in main
   sandbox.enable_sandbox(config)
     File "/Users/kennethryan/Projects/go-edu-store/y/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 183, in enable_sandbox
   __import__('%s.threading' % dist27.__name__)
     File "/Users/kennethryan/Projects/go-edu-store/y/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/dist27/threading.py", line 13, in <module>
   from time import time as _time, sleep as _sleep
     File "/Users/kennethryan/Projects/go-edu-store/y/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py", line 984, in load_module
   raise ImportError('No module named %s' % fullname)
     ImportError: No module named time
   ```

Here is my current $PATH:

```
/Users/kennethryan/Projects/go-edu-store/y/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Can you show the code, please?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as this is an inactive year old issue, we can assume that updating the Google Cloud tools to their latest versions by running '`gcloud components update`' will fix this.

Also ensuring that you are using the Python installation provided by [GCloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/), and that there are no conflicting 'CLOUDSDK_PYTHON' environment variables should prevent this.

---

If this issue is seen again in the future, it is recommended to directly report this to the [Google Public Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) so that this can be properly handled and triaged to the GCloud engineering team.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolved this problem by setting
`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/` where `timemodule.so` file is located.